# onclick returns input from form instead of redirecting

Tags: javascript, html, forms, jsp

I am just learning JS and I am trying to navigate to a different page based on the input from the user. `/MenuDemo1/src/home.jsp`

In the above the two text boxes are coming and after I enter the values and click on the button, I am successful in getting the uid and pwd but on click instead of the url in location.href, it is going to `MenuDemo1/src/home.jsp?username=admin&password=admin.`

```
<form name="form1" id="form1" >
    First name: <input type="text" name="username"> <br> Last
    name: <input type="password" name="password"> <br> 
    <button id="submit" onclick="validateform()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

```
<script>
    var linkHome;
    function validateform() {
        var uid = document.getElementById("form1").elements[0].value;
        var pwd = document.getElementById("form1").elements[1].value;

        if (uid === "admin" && pwd === "admin") {
            document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "Found elements in the form.";
            linkHome = "/MenuDemo1/src/adminHome.jsp";
        } else {
            linkHome = "/MenuDemo1/src/userHome.jsp";
        }
        location.href = linkHome;
    }

</script>
```

Can someone please point it out what I am missing? TIA.

Comment: In some browsers (like chrome), `location.href` is considered unsafe and is blocked. this could be the case. Instead use `window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";`

Comment: change that button and use anchor tag

Comment: it still appends username=admin&password=admin this to the original url. Ie /MenuDemo1/src/home.jsp becomes /MenuDemo1/src/home.jsp?username=admin&password=admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to attach the function to your submit for event : 
because onclick will not trigger the reirection :

so first remove the `onclick="validateform()"` 
and then assign the function to the submit event and put `return false;` to prevent send form to the post url ;

js should look like belllow :

```
var linkHome;
document.getElementById("form1").onsubmit = function validateform() {
  var uid = document.getElementById("form1").elements[0].value;
  var pwd = document.getElementById("form1").elements[1].value;

  if (uid === "admin" && pwd === "admin") {
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "Found elements in the form.";
    linkHome = "/MenuDemo1/src/adminHome.jsp";
  } else {
    linkHome = "/MenuDemo1/src/userHome.jsp";
  }
  location.href = linkHome;
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer may not be correct, I am 11 and started programming about 9 months ago, so I am  a noob. But I believe it is not working because you have no paragraph to where the data can be sent to, so when I ran the program and did this edit it worked.`'

Also i believe there is no page such as "/MenuDemo1/src/adminHome.jsp" to go to

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <form name="form1" id="form1" >
    First name: <input type="text" name="username"> <br> Last
    name: <input type="password" name="password"> <br> 
    <button id="submit" onclick="validateform()">Submit</button>
</form>
<p id="demo1"></p>
<script>
        var linkHome;
    function validateform() {
    var uid = document.getElementById("form1").elements[0].value;
    var pwd = document.getElementById("form1").elements[1].value;

    if (uid === "admin" && pwd === "admin") {
        document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "Found elements in the form.";
        linkHome = "/MenuDemo1/src/adminHome.jsp";
    } else {
        linkHome = "/MenuDemo1/src/userHome.jsp";
    }
    location.href = linkHome;
}

</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body >

  </body>
</html>`
```

Comment: Thanks. But the page does exists. And thanks for the paragraph. Got deleted somehow. But ignoring that part, the concern is the redirecting part.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this :-

```
linkHome = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "MenuDemo1/src/adminHome.jsp";
```

and

```
linkHome = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "MenuDemo1/src/userHome.jsp";
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, Any idea why  
it still appends username=admin&password=admin this to the original url. Ie /MenuDemo1/src/home.jsp becomes /MenuDemo1/src/home.jsp?username=admin&password=admin.

Comment: Since, no "method" attribute has been specified to the form, thus by default an HTTP 'GET' request will be made wherein the two fields in your form which have a "name" attribute defined will be added to the URL as query parameters.

A fix should be to remove the 'id="submit"' from the button and then it should work alright.